Elo rating for a game with a cap on winrate
This gamedev post asks about a rating system for a contest that has a significant and unavoidable random chance. For the sake of this question, let's suppose the game is "dicechess":

Player 1 rolls a 10-sided die. If they roll a 10, they instantly win, and if they roll a 1 they instantly lose.
On any other outcome, the players play chess and the outcome of chess is the outcome of the contest.

Since Elo rating depends on the assumption of log odds (an 1800-elo player has 10:1 odds against a 1400 and 100:1 against a 1000), but the actual winrate is capped at 90%, the standard method unfairly punishes players for playing against low-ranked opponents.
Can we fix this by making the expected outcome function saturate at 0.1/0.9?
$$\sigma(r) = 0.1 + 0.8\left(\frac{1}{1 + 10^{-r/s}}\right)$$
Does this change the update rule? Does it maintain the properties that make Elo desirable in the first place?
